Finiteness of the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| \ln(|f|) dx $
Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| \ln(|f|)  dx < +\infty$ would this even imply  $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| \ln_{+}(|f|)  dx < +\infty$?
For finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ this would be easy by using $|f| \ln_{+}(|f|) \leq  |f| \ln(|f|) + 1.$ But this is not applicable for unbounded sets. Is there a possibility here too or a counter-example?
$\ln_{+}(x) := \max ( \ln(x),0 )$ denotes here the positive part of $\ln(x).$
Edit: My idea would be to consider
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| \ln(|f|)  dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| \ln_{+}(|f|)  dx - \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| \ln_{-}(|f|)  dx.$ And
$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| \ln_{-}(|f|)  dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| \ln_{-}(|f|) \, \mathbb{1}[|f| \leq 1] dx.$

Usually, when we bring up an integral, like $\int_\mathbb{R} |f| \ln(|f|)\,dx$ and put it in an inequality as an assumption, that means that we're assuming the integral exists.  In the context of the Lebesgue integral, that means at least one of the negative or positive parts has a finite integral.  Saying it's $< + \infty$ means the positive part must have a finite integral, which is what you've asked.
That is, as a matter of theoretical/notational necessity, saying something like $\int f < \infty$ necessitates $\int f_+ < \infty$.

As far as I know, only if we write that the absolute value of an integral is finite, we are assuming that the positive and/or negative part exists. But the function $t \ln(t)$ is not positive everywhere, it is negative for $0<t<1.$ And there are functions for which the integral of $g$ is finite but of $|g|$ is not, like $sin(x)/x$ over $\mathbb{R}.$ Maybe it is notationally not correct what I wrote.

@kumquat For Lebesgue integrals, the integration is done by integrating the positive and negative parts separately and taking the difference.  If at least one of the parts isn't finite, then the integral has no value at all, not even $\pm \infty$, as $\infty-\infty$ is not well defined.  Functions like $\sin(x)/x$ are not Lebesgue integrable.

@kumquat The Lebesgue integral of $\sin(x)/ x$ over $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't exist.  It only exists as an improper integral (my terminology may be a bit rusty, but I think we'd often talk about such an integral in the topic of singular integrals)

Thanks for the clarification. But how can I ensure that $|f| \ln(|f|)$ is Lebesgue integrable and it does not just exist as an improper integral? Sorry, my notation is probably unfortunate or incorrectly chosen.

That's fairly vague... To get to the core of the matter faster, what is the source of your question/confusion?  Did you see something in an article/textbook and thought it was incorrect?  Or perhaps you're stuck on an exercise?  The more context you give, the more likely someone will answer the question you want to have answered rather than a different interpretation of the question you've actually asked.
